# Как можно реализовать выпадающий список в html, передавая данный список через flask?

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Через flask:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
return render_template('our.html', option=list)
```

передаем в нашу html список (на самом деле, получающийся из респонса с другого сервера и может иметь разную длину). Из него хотелось бы создать выпадающее окно с выбором по типу такого:

```html
<p>Выберите файл:</p>
<p><input type="search" list="character">
  <datalist id="character">
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
   </datalist></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно в `out.html` написать выражение, которое поймет генератор шаблона.

Попробуйте:

```
<p>Выберите файл:</p>
<p><input type="search" list="character">
  <datalist id="character">
  {% for opt in option %}
    <option value="{{ opt }}"></option>
  {% endfor %}
  </datalist>
</p>
```

---

**PS.**

Недавно делал [подобное](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/cdfcc9de7900558737ebfc985257ecd34934439c/flask__webservers/hash__md5_sha1_etc/main.py#L53), но заполнял список хешей. Там тот же цикл-генератор, но с условием

Comment: ```html
<form action="0.0.0.0:5000/to/<form_choise>" method="post">
     <p>Выберите файл:</p>
     <p><input type="search" list="character">
         <datalist id="character">
         {% for opt in option %}
             <option value="{{ opt }}"></option>
         {% endfor %}
         </datalist>
     </p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
  </form>
```
Можно ли такое провернуть, если form_choise и есть наш выбор из формы?

Comment: @PolarNight, можно с чем угодно провернуть -- этот шаблон генерации работает с строками